# Duplicate records in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was wondering if somebody has dealt with a similar problem before. I am trying to extract data from a legacy database that I moved to mysql. For some reason its author thought that it was a good idea to duplicate records. So the quote table I deal with looks like:

```
 id     code     quote_no             client
 1      A      Qte 2013/001-A       John Smith
 2      A/B    Qte 2013/002-A/B     Mark Brown
 3      A      Qte 2013/002-A       Mark Brown
 4      B      Qte 2013/002-B       Mark Brown
```

There is nothing directly indicating that ids 2,3,4 belong together. Code refers to department.

I want to separate unique and 'compound' records such as Qte 2013/002-A/B and Qte 2013/001-A. Basically to get one quote_no per unique numeric quote_no. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the format of quote_no (`Qte ****/***-***)` remains the same across the table?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the output should be. Can you post a sample of what the deduplicated rowset should look like?

Comment: The format mostly remains the same. The output I am after is id 1 and 2. Without duplication like the 'sub-quotes' with id 3 and 4. Hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the quote_no has a fixed format, you can GROUP() on a substring of the quote_no and get all the records with their respective counts.

From there, it should take a JOIN with the original table to remove all the duplicate rows, with the WHERE condition of (code LIKE '/' or count =1) to account for cherrypicking compound and unique records respectively.

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77bc7/15/0).